# Shopware 6 - Get products associated to a a specific sales channel from a product repository

Tags: shopware

**Situation**

I am building a CLI-command to get all products, which are associated to a given sales-channel. For example i would like to have all products from the B2B-channel.

**Current approach**

From reading the documentation my understanding is that i need to do the following:

1. Create a sales-channel context using the `Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactory`
2. Pass `context` to a product repository

Here is some pseudo-code. I use the `RepositoryIterator` but basically it just wraps any `EntityRepositoryInterface`. In this case a product repository.

```
$options = [
    SalesChannelContextService::LANGUAGE_ID => MY_STORE::B2B
];
$salesChannelContext = $this->salesChannelContextFactory->create('', $this->salesChannelId, $options);
return new RepositoryIterator($productRepository, $this->salesChannelContext->getContext(), $criteria);
```

What i get now if i loop through the repository is still a list of all entities instead of the one specific to the provided sales channel.

So what i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out now. It seems like that the `SalesChannelContext` is not enough. You also need to add a filter. This is the expected behaviour in the admin-area.

So this would be the criteria:

```
...
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('visibilities.salesChannel.id', [$this->salesChannelId]));
...

return new RepositoryIterator($this->productRepository, $this->salesChannelContext->getContext(), $criteria);
```

It still does not feel intuitive as the responsibility of the `SalesChannelContext` is not clear for me.

Comment: The use of the Criteria-Object and adding filters to it is completely correct.

But you shouldn't create a `SalesChannelContext` from scratch, rather you should use the `Context` or `SalesChannelContext` that is provided by the concrete entrypoint (e.g. from the event you listen on etc.) you use. In the context information like the used language and currency is configured, so the DataAbstractionLayer will fetch the correct data for you. The SalesChannelContext internally uses the Context, but has also additionall information, like the logged in customer, the shipping address and the cart.

Comment: The `salesChannelContext` is only available when a request is made against some storefront or store-api route, on "normal" api routes only the "normal" context is available.

Comment: I am using the `SalesChannelContextFactory` in my service. Basically the starting point is a plain Symfony command. So in this case i inject it as a service dependency to construct the context. 

https://github.com/shopware/core/blob/trunk/System/DependencyInjection/sales_channel.xml

```
 <service id="Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactory">
</service>
```